# Custom WPF UserControl with custom TextBox: Text gets out of sync when input is invalid

Tags: wpf, user-controls, textbox

I'm creating a custom `TextBox` (`TimeTextBox`) for typing in time values. The idea is that the user just types in the numbers, and the time digits will be filled in from right to left, like a cash register.

[image: TimeInput Design]

I created a new UserControl, `TimeInput`, which has a `Time` `DependencyProperty`:

```
public DateTime Time
    {
        get { return (DateTime)GetValue(TimeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TimeProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TimeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Time",
                                    typeof(DateTime),
                                    typeof(TimeInput),
                                    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(DateTime.Today, (s, e) => (s as TimeInput).NotifyPropertyChanged("ProxyTime")) { BindsTwoWayByDefault = true });
```

`TimeInput` also has a public property, `ProxyTime`:

```
public DateTime ProxyTime
    {
        get { return Time; }
        set
        {
            if (Time.Hour != value.Hour || Time.Minute != value.Minute)
                Time = new DateTime(Time.Year, Time.Month, Time.Day, value.Hour, value.Minute, 0, 0);
        }
    }
```

`TimeTextBox`'s `Text` binds to `ProxyTime`, to prevent the date component of the Time `DependencyProperty` from changing when the user changes the time. The Time `DependencyProperty` has a `PropertyChangedCallback`, which calls `NotifyPropertyChanged` for `ProxyTime`, to update the `TimeTextBox`'s Text when necessary.

This does not work well when the user types in an invalid time. Suppose the Time value was 01:30, and the user changes it to 25:30. The `Time` `DependencyProperty` does not get updated with 25:30 since it's invalid, but the `TimeTextBox`'s Text property has 25:30. Now if the backing object is reset, the Time will be set to 01:30 again, but the PropertyChangedCallback does not get called because  from the DependencyProperty's perspective, the value has not changed. Thus, NotifyPropertyChanged does not get called for ProxyTime, and the TimeTextBox's text will still contain 25:30.

I'm not sure how to create this UserControl such that the bound `DateTime`'s date does not get changed, while the `Text`'s value is updated properly when the prior value was invalid.

Comment: can you please show where you call NotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: I updated the question with the declaration for TimeProperty. NotifyPropertyChanged is called in the lambda expression passed in to the FrameworkPropertyMetaData constructor